# How do I modify a multilevel list in MS Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I'm looking at the MS Word 2007 official help page for [multilevel lists](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-a-multilevel-list-HA010065017.aspx), however I could not find any information regarding modifying them just like the way I can (right-click and) modify Styles.

How do I modify a multilevel list in MS Word 2007?

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on any multi-level list number.
2. Select the option "Adjust List Indents..." and click on it.
3. In the box that opens click and open the  "Format" tab which is at the  bottom.
4. Select "Numbering..." option that is displayed.
5. You will then find that the Modify Multilevel List box is opened displaying the current multilevel style.
6. Go ahead and modify as required.